# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ when I compile a c++ project

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, c++17, hook, expected-condition

I'm having this error when trying to compile a cpp hook project

```
/root/lib-173/hook.cpp:14:77: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 rcmp::hook_function<0x0809472A, int(gplayer_imp*, int, const void*, size_t)>([](auto original, gplayer_imp* self, int cmd_type, const void* buf, size_t size) {
                                                                             ^
/root/lib-173/hook.cpp:23:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 });
```

I'm using the project: https://github.com/Smertig/rcmp to hook a function, but when compiling I receive the error presented

my hook.cpp file :

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch2/catch.hpp"

#include <rcmp.hpp>

#include <array>
 

struct gplayer_imp; 




rcmp::hook_function<0x0809472A, int(gplayer_imp*, int, const void*, size_t)>([](auto original, gplayer_imp* self, int cmd_type, const void* buf, size_t size) {
  
  if (cmd_type == 174 && size < 6) {
    
    return 0;
  }

 
  return original(self, cmd_type, buf, size);
});
```

my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(hook)


set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


set(SOURCE_FILES hook.cpp)


add_library(hook SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})


target_compile_options(hook PRIVATE -std=c++17)


add_subdirectory(/root/lib-173/rcmp)


include_directories(/root/lib-173/rcmp/include)


target_link_libraries(hook PRIVATE rcmp)
```

Unfortunately, all changes were failures, since depending on the code, rcmp does not accept the new standard.
I tried adding other headers or modifying CMakeLists.txt but I was unsuccessful.

What should be done to fix it?

If I already have the answer I haven't found it.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: What do you expect the line that the compiler complains about to mean? Is it supposed to be a function definition? If so, what is the lambda in the function parameter supposed to mean and why does it have template arguments? Is it supposed to be an expression statement with a function call instead? If so, a expression statements can only appear at block scope (i.e. function body) in C++, not at file/namespace scope. The line is just not valid C++ syntax where it is written.

Comment: how it should be? 
I followed the rcmp application model but I'm not sure if I did it correctly, so I'm asking for help.
It hooks into an application, filters the application and returns a value to it, or just makes the function continue. It's not a new function, just a treatment... 
but I'm not sure if that's right

Comment: You can't call a function at global scope. That's nothing special about this library, but just basics of C++. In the same way that you also can't write `std::cout << "Hello world!";` outside a function at global scope.